# DTO to BeanWrapperImpl

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

How heavy in terms of performance penalty if BeanWrapperImpl is used to wrap a target DTO class and its properties set via setPropertyValue() methods and iterated over a loop. For example.

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl;
import package.dto.DTO1;

....

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    DTO dto1 = new DTO();
    BeanWrapperImpl wrapper = new BeanWrapperImpl(dto1);
    wrapper.setPropertyValue("property1", map.get("property1");
    wrapper.setPropertyValue("property2", map.get("property2");
}
```

Comment: It's both heavyweight and clumsy. Instead, use a tool such as MapStruct, which can generate mappings of this sort at compile-time in a fast and debuggable manner.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- Thank you for recommending MapStruct! It's exactly what I needed.